# How to mock a function in python which is called in the global scope of a module using Pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I have written the following function in "sample.py" and corresponding test script in "test_sample.py". The main function roll_dice is in module named "dice.py". All these files are in a folder called "myapp".

**Scenario 1**

*dice.py*

```
import random
def roll_dice():
    print("rolling...")
    return random.randint(1, 6)
```

*sample.py*

```
from myapp.dice import roll_dice
def guess_number(num):
    result = roll_dice()
    if result == num:
        return "You won!"
    else:
        return "You lost!"
```

*test_sample.py*

```
@mock.patch("myapp.sample.roll_dice")
def test_guess_number(mock_roll_dice):
    mock_roll_dice.return_value = 3
    assert guess_number(3) == "You won!"
```

When I run the test using Pytest, it runs successfully. But when I make a small change in sample.py shown below, the test fails:

**Scenario 2**

*sample.py*

```
from myapp.dice import roll_dice
result = roll_dice() # Here is the change
def guess_number(num):
    if result == num:
        return "You won!"
    else:
        return "You lost!"
```

Rest everything remains same!

Instead of calling function inside another function, when I call it in the global scope of sample.py module, test fails. Can someone tell me how to mock the roll_dice function in Scenario 2?

My guess is that we can not mock function calls in global scope of a module. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

In the scenario 2, `roll_dice` is call at import time.
Complete `test_sample.py` should be:

```py
from myapp.sample import guess_number      # Call to `roll_dice` is done here
                                           # before mock

@mock.patch("myapp.sample.roll_dice")
def test_guess_number(mock_roll_dice):
    mock_roll_dice.return_value = 3
    assert guess_number(3) == "You won!"
```

If you move import inside test function, it don't work too, because `patch("myapp.sample.roll_dice")` will import `myapp.sample` before mocking.

It will work with:

```py
@mock.patch("myapp.dice.roll_dice")
def test_guess_number(mock_roll_dice):
    from myapp.sample import guess_number  # Call to `roll_dice` is done here
                                           # You shouldn't have imported `myapp.sample`
                                           # before
    mock_roll_dice.return_value = 3
    assert guess_number(3) == "You won!"
```

But be careful with code executed at import time (global variable initialization). At final the only thing you test is your knowledge of the mock library.

Answer (score -1):

The order is

1. Import sample.py from test_sample.py
2. Init the global variable result
3. Patch roll_dice from mock.patch"
4. Execute the test function

When you import the `sample.py` from `test_sample.py`, the value of the global variable `result` will be initialized, but the patching function `roll_dice` needs to wait until the test fixtures initialized.

The `results` always initialized before `mock.patching`, so the value always comes from the original function instead of mocked one.